# What data treatment/transformation should be applied if there are a lot of outliers (identified via boxplot)?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, data-cleaning, outliers

I referred to this [post](https://machinelearningmastery.com/quick-and-dirty-data-analysis-with-pandas/) and used [pandas boxplot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.boxplot.html) to plot my numerical predictors and target variable and got the following result (*pid demand* being the target, rest all predictor variables):
[predictor_target_boxplot_img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CayMn.png) .
I am confused as to how can there be so many outliers (considering points above whiskers) and if they are indeed genuine outliers then how to handle them?

Comment: This is more a statistic question than a programming one. There are many different ways of dealing with outliers and it depends on your data and your goals. However, you may decide to exclude the outliers from the plot `boxplot(your_data, showfliers=False)`. The numbers of outliers should be compared to the total number of data points, what is the percentage of outliers in your data?

Comment: it's fairly large. for example, if i consider outliers on the basis of target variable (pid_demand), considering the whisker value to be threshold, they form nearly 10% of the total data points. similarly for my predictor variables, outliers contribute to 7-8% of total set. my concern is if my understanding of deriving outliers from the plot here is correct or not since how can a data have 10% outliers in it?

Comment: It can very well be. Real world data is loaded with outliers :) I suggest plotting your data differently (line, scatter, etc) and see if it's really as you expect. Also, if the distribution of the data is what you expect (normal distribution?) if everything matches with your expectations, then you may decide to discard the outliers or to treat them as a separate group. But again, this is a statistical problem rather than a programming one, you may want to move this post somewhere else.

Comment: thanks for helping, can you suggest some active communities where i could post this?

Comment: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/  or  https://math.stackexchange.com/ or https://stats.stackexchange.com/ should do.

Answer (score 0):

> You may cap all the outliers which are being 3-SD (Standard
>   Deviations) away to a certain value and continue with analysis.

```
df[ df > value_greater_than_SDaway ] = value_to_be_replaced_with
```